# How to set LevelLineLength for a Candlestick from xaml code

Tags: xaml, devexpress

I have a candlestick defined:

```
<dxc:CandleStickSeries2D x:Name="mainCandle">
</dxc:CandleStickSeries2D>
```

I would like to set the LevelLineLength=0.5 from within my xaml file.

How is this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me why do you want to set the LevelLineLength property for the candle stick series because there are no any level lines in [2D Candle Stick chart](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6850).
Do you mean the [StockSeries2D.LevelLineLength](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfChartsStockSeries2D_LevelLineLengthtopic) property of [2D Stock chart](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6849)?
Or for candle stick use the [CandleStickSeries2D.CandleWidth](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfChartsCandleStickSeries2D_CandleWidthtopic) property.

Related examples:
 - [How to create a 2D Stock chart](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1684)
 - [How to create a 2D Candle Stick chart](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1685)

Comment: Hi,I would like to modify the space between candlesticks. I thought this is how it should be done. When I increase the candlewidth, the candles begin to overlap

Comment: @coder4crack Hi, I believe this is yet another question. Have i answered the original one? If yes, you should accept the answer or specify additional details. Anyway, it is better to ask the DevExpress related question at [DevExpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) rather the at SO.